# Sql query to show some results using PHP

Tags: php, sql

at the end of this I want to display the TITLES of the results that have *extra1* as meta_key and *test* as meta_value.

My goal is to:

1. From table **wp_postmeta** get the **post_id** of every row that has *extra1* as **meta_key** and *test* as **meta_value**
2. Using the **post_id**, get the **post_title** for every row on step 1 respectively.
3. Print the **post_title**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the query assuming you are working on [wordpress database schema](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png):

```
SELECT post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT post_id
   FROM wp_postmeta
   WHERE meta_key = 'extra1' AND meta_value = 'test'
)
```

*second query after Mairy's comment:*

```
SELECT post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT post_id
   FROM wp_postmeta
   WHERE meta_key IN('extra1','extra2','extra3') AND meta_value IN('test','test1','test2','test3')
)
```

then you just need to loop over th result set with php and then print the post title as you prefer:

```
//connect to DB then ($query contains the query above)
$res = mysql_query($query, $db);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   echo($row['post_title']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! How can I edit this to satisfy multiple meta_keys and meta_values using AND?

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thank you for your help. However I want to ask if this is a slow query.

Comment: propably with a JOIN it could be faster. But i guess that if you have right indexes set on meta_key it should run pretty fast